# How to store function pointers in map and invoke them?

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, pointers, stl

I want to create class which should containe map with function pointers (subscribers). But that functions can be with different signature. My code looks like this but it not completed and I am not sure if that is right. Can somebody help me please how to correct append pointers to map and invoke them in `myMainClass::start()`?

**myMainClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "iostream";
#include "mySubscriber.h"

struct myMainClass {
    myMainClass() {}
    ~myMainClass() {}

    bool callback1(int iData) {
        std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << std::endl;
    }

    bool callback2(std::string sData) {
        std::cout << "callback 2 with sData " << sData << std::endl;
    }

    bool callback3(int iData, std::string sData) {
        std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << ", sData " << sData << std::endl;
    }

    // SHOULD BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    bool start() {
        mySubscriber ss;
        ss.subscribe("callback1", callback1);
        ss.subscribe("callback2", callback2);
        ss.getSubscribe("callback1")(5);
        ss.getSubscribe("callback2")("test");
    }
};
```

**mySubscriber.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "map";
#include "string";
#include "functional";

class mySubscriber {
    typedef std::function<void()> func;
    std::map<std::string, func*> _subscribes;

public:
    mySubscriber() : _subscribes{} {}
    ~mySubscriber() {
        _subscribes.clear();
    }

    /*
    * append or change function pointer
    */
    void subscribe(std::string fName, func* f) {
        auto find = _subscribes.find(fName);
        if (find != _subscribes.end())
        {
            find->second = f;
        }
        else
        {
            _subscribes.emplace(fName, f);
        }
    }

    /*
    * get subscribe function
    */
    func* getSubscribe(std::string fName) {
        auto find = _subscribes.find(fName);
        if (find != _subscribes.end())
        {
            return find->second;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

Comment: Member function pointers are not regular function pointers

Comment: how to make it with pointers to member functions?

Comment: You have to provide an instance of `myMainClass` to call a member function of it. Where you do that will influence how to change what you have

Comment: aside: you can simplify `subscribe` to `_subscribes[fName] = f;` (or `_subscribes.insert_or_assign(fName, f);`)

Comment: A "pointer to `std::function<void()>`" **is not** a function pointer, `void(*)()` is.

Comment: I did with `typedef bool(myMainClass::* myptr)(int);` but I don't need exactly function signature.

Comment: maybe needed some kind of wrapper for functions

Comment: I would _strongly_ suggest not putting them all in the same map, and instead having separate maps per signature. It never makes sense to put functions with different signatures in the same data structure.  Separate maps leads to simpler and faster code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first some general hints:**

- Avoid raw pointer usage as far as possible, even for internals! Use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr instead!
- Reducing a data conglomerate to a standard container, indexing it via a dynamic data type like std::string and use it in a plain void std::function context results (almost?) always in type erasure and a loss of according type safe outer access. In fact, this even has nothing to do with further differences between plain functions and member methods in the first place.

**A possible first solution approach:**

This is a minimal working example that should cover your quite dynamic requirements. For me it compiles and runs well with MS VS 2017 (C++17). I tried to use your original structs as far as possible.

```
#include <variant>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct myMainClass {
  myMainClass() {}
  ~myMainClass() {}

  bool callback1(int iData) {
    std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  bool callback2(std::string sData) {
    std::cout << "callback 2 with sData " << sData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  bool callback3(int iData, std::string sData) {
    std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << ", sData " << sData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  template <typename T> class CallbackBaseTmpl;
  template <typename Ret, typename ...Args> 
  class CallbackBaseTmpl<Ret(Args...)> 
  {
  public:
    using Signature = Ret(Args...);

    CallbackBaseTmpl(const std::function<Signature>& func) : m_function(func) {}
    CallbackBaseTmpl(std::function<Signature>&& func) : 
     m_function(std::move(func)) {}

    inline Ret Func(Args&&... args) { return m_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

  private:
    std::function<Signature> m_function;
  };

  class Callback1Type : public CallbackBaseTmpl<bool(int)>
  {
    using CallbackBaseTmpl::CallbackBaseTmpl;
  };

  class Callback2Type : public CallbackBaseTmpl<bool(std::string)>
  {
    using CallbackBaseTmpl::CallbackBaseTmpl;
  };

  class Callback3Type : public CallbackBaseTmpl<bool(int, std::string)>
  {
    using CallbackBaseTmpl::CallbackBaseTmpl;
  };

  using CompoundCallbackType = std::variant<Callback1Type, Callback2Type, Callback3Type>;
  class CallbackHolder
  {
  public:
    CallbackHolder(const CompoundCallbackType& callbackImpl) : m_callbacksImpl(callbackImpl) {}

    inline auto getIndex() const { return m_callbacksImpl.index(); }
    inline CompoundCallbackType& getImpl() const { return m_callbacksImpl; }

  private:
    mutable CompoundCallbackType m_callbacksImpl;
  };

  class CallbacksContainer
  {
  public:

    template <typename VariantType>
    bool subscribe(const VariantType& compoundType)
    {
      return subscribe(CallbackHolder(compoundType));
    }

    bool subscribe(const CallbackHolder& cHolder)
    {
      auto res = m_containerImpl.insert(cHolder);
      return res.second;
    }

    template <typename CallbackType, typename... Args>
    auto getSubscribe(Args&&... args)
    {
      // linear search - can be optimized
      for (auto& implEntry : m_containerImpl)
      {
        bool isWanted = std::visit([&args...](auto&& arg) {
          using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
          if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, CallbackType>)
            return true;
          else
            return false;
          }, implEntry.getImpl());

        if (isWanted)
          return std::get<CallbackType>(implEntry.getImpl()).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
      throw std::logic_error("Cannot access element");
    }

  private:

    struct CustomComparer {
      bool operator() (const CallbackHolder& lhs, const CallbackHolder& rhs) const
      {
        // Each variant entry allowed only once in the set
        return lhs.getIndex() < rhs.getIndex();
      }
    };

    std::set<CallbackHolder, CustomComparer> m_containerImpl;
  };

  bool start() {
    CallbacksContainer ms;
    ms.subscribe(Callback1Type(std::bind(&myMainClass::callback1, this, std::placeholders::_1)));
    ms.subscribe(Callback2Type(std::bind(&myMainClass::callback2, this, std::placeholders::_1)));

    ms.getSubscribe<Callback1Type>(5);
    ms.getSubscribe<Callback2Type>("TEST");

    ms.subscribe(Callback3Type(std::bind(&myMainClass::callback3, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
    ms.getSubscribe<Callback3Type>(2, "");

    return true;
  }
};
```

Explanation: I replaced your original map with an std::set as a kind of registry container so there are still no duplicates allowed. Some efforts are required via Wrappers to achieve the desired final access scheme.
You can easily change the desired registered functions for a type in a dynamic but always very type safe way now. Feel free to extend this scheme for your own purposes. Likely, there are several parts that can be optimized, shortened or extended. Maybe there's also a nice way to avoid this mutable inside the CallbackHolder. The (non-grave for a few functions) linear search within the set can be avoided via an actual typeid sorting and specialized according finding for instance.

**Update due to feedback:**

If strings as keys are required and a maximum degree of freedom should be given, i.e. any callback type should be providable without the necessity for compile time registration, this solution might be an alternative:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct myMainClass {
  myMainClass() {}
  ~myMainClass() {}

  bool callback1(int iData) {
    std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  bool callback2(std::string sData) {
    std::cout << "callback 2 with sData " << sData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  bool callback3(int iData, std::string sData) {
    std::cout << "callback 1 with iData " << iData << ", sData " << sData << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  class ICallback 
  { 
  public: 
    virtual ~ICallback() = default; 
  };

  template <typename T> class TypedCallback;
  template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
  class TypedCallback<Ret(Args...)> : public ICallback
  {
  public:
    using Signature = Ret(Args...);

    TypedCallback(const std::function<Signature>& func) : m_function(func) {}
    TypedCallback(std::function<Signature>&& func) :
      m_function(std::move(func)) {}

    inline Ret Func(Args&&... args) { return m_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

  private:
    std::function<Signature> m_function;
  };

  class CallbacksContainer
  {
  private:

    template <typename T> struct CallTraits {};
    template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct CallTraits<Ret(C::*)(Args...)>
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);
      using ReturnType = Ret;
    };
    template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct CallTraits<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const>
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);
      using ReturnType = Ret;
    };

    template <typename F>
    struct FuncTraits
    {
      using FuncClass = std::decay_t<F>;
      using OperatorSignature = decltype(&FuncClass::operator());
      using signature = typename CallTraits<OperatorSignature>::Signature;
      using returnType = typename CallTraits<OperatorSignature>::ReturnType;
    };

    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct FuncTraits<Ret(Args...)>
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);
      using ReturnType = Ret;
    };
    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct FuncTraits<Ret(*)(Args...)>
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);
      using ReturnType = Ret;
    };
    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct FuncTraits<Ret(&)(Args...)>
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);
      using ReturnType = Ret;
    };

  public:

    template <typename T>
    bool subscribe(const std::string& key, T&& func)
    {
      auto res = m_subscriptions.try_emplace(
        key, std::make_unique<TypedCallback<typename FuncTraits<T>::signature>>(std::forward<T>(func)));
      return res.second;
    }

    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    auto getSubscribe(const std::string& key, Args&&... args) const
    {
      using Signature = Ret(Args...);

      const auto& entry = m_subscriptions.at(key);
      auto rp = entry.get();
      auto typedCB = dynamic_cast<TypedCallback<Signature>*>(rp);
      if (typedCB == nullptr)
      {
        // TODO: Possible further check if functor can be used due to convertible types, for instance
        // with an acyclic visitor?
        std::logic_error("Wrong callback signature provided.");
      }

      return typedCB->Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

  private:

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ICallback>> m_subscriptions;
  };

  bool start() {
    CallbacksContainer ms;

    // Usage with non static member methods
    ms.subscribe("callback1", [this](int x) { return callback1(x); });
    ms.subscribe("callback2", [this](std::string x) { return callback2(x); });
    ms.subscribe("callback3", [this](int x, std::string str) { return callback3(x, str); });
    
    // Usage with lambda
    ms.subscribe("callback4", [](int y) { return y != 0; });

    // Usage with std::function itself
    ms.subscribe("callback5", std::function<bool(int)>([](int y) { return y != 0; }));

    // Getters - Unfortunately, exact types are required. Maybe acyclic visitor could help here?
    ms.getSubscribe<bool>("callback1", 1);
    ms.getSubscribe<bool>("callback2", std::string("TEST"));
    ms.getSubscribe<bool>("callback3", 1, std::string("TEST"));
    ms.getSubscribe<bool>("callback4", 1);

    return true;
  }
};
```

PROs:

- No static/compile time method signature registration required -> no variants
- At least with C++20, method subscription will be an easy going here, added some helper traits to make things a bit easier here already
- Only one underlying map used

CONs:

- Less type-safety at some points and the dynamic_cast might be a bit slow but might be improved in terms of performance via a simple type index comparison
- The getSubscribe() method has to be used with care. Exact types are required here (the former dynamically registered ones) and it doesn't unfortunately support common signature conversion ways. I see currently no way to get rid of this problem with pre C++20 features. Maybe some tricks with a generic acyclic visitor pattern or SFINAE magic + visitor might help here but that breaks the mould by far here I think. If that arises as a real issue, one can still use the chained parameter scheme in doubt, that guarantees type safety on its own.

Comment: I need to pass member function with different signature as callback.

Comment: I added a source code example to my original comment. Feel free for questions and critics!

Comment: Too late seen... I changed the behavior of your subscribing in not allowing overwrites now. Should be an easy work for you to fix this.

Comment: can you please recheck the code because some errors exists @secundi

Comment: copy constructor for `CallbackBaseTmpl` is bad. Should be `CallbackBaseTmpl(const std::function<Signature>& func) : m_function(func) {}` and after bool start method class should be closed with `};`

Comment: Sorry, that where typos occurred during copying from the IDE here. Should work now.

Comment: I woudl strongly suggest not using `std::variant` and instead having separate maps per signature. It never makes sense to put functions with different signatures in the same data structure.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Says who a priori? The usage of variants in std::containers is a common scheme, here it's even an internal. The direct call operator is just a simplification of this usage and the common base scheme is that it summarizes dynamically bound functors/signatures.A possible usage case I can imagine is a script-parse-scenario where you want to map the C++ internals as precise as possible. Dozends of maps in doubt on the other hand have their drawbacks too...

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243f97df089439f4 Upsides: There's no linear search, the call is done at compile time, less code. Downsides: ?

Comment: Yes if you want to keep strings as keys, that's a good way to got but it's not type safe with focus on the keys and the at()-Operator perforrns logarithmically. For my example, the linear search can be reduced to a logarithmical one simply too. I don't know what you mean with compile time call. My example solely has to do some steps further but the call itself is as type safe as your approach with the difference, that in my example you cannot be flexible with the signature for one dedicated key but on the other hand you get compile time errors then. Depends on the OP's intents what to prefer.

Comment: @Secundi it is not convinient to use variant. Signatures can be different and for one case I can use one set of callbacks but for another case another set of callbacks. Can you please make another version with map instead of variant?

Comment: To be more clear, I need for example `myMainClass1` and `myMainClass2` which can use class `Subscriber` where it can hold functions with their signature. For `myMainClass1` I can add one set of callbacks and for `myMainClass2` another set.

Comment: I depends on what you want to achieve exactly and where exactly you might require type safety. It also depends on how your class will be used (maybe within an interface context?) With Mooning Duck's way you have maps as internals and you are flexible with your strings but "external sides" have no chance to provide the right signature in doubt, at least not compile time safe. What is the final purpose for this subscribing ecxactly?

Comment: Maybe we should discuss that in chat.

Comment: I want to inherit that `Subscriber` class, that code was as example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225466/discussion-between-pasha-and-secundi).

Comment: @Secundi: After reading your code, we're solving entirely different problems. I made something that allows N listeners for each named event that can share signatures, and yours allows for 1 callback per signature.

Comment: I also realized my variant could be refactored to use "recursive" templates to reduce per-signature boilerplate. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76aa3aa6d8ae8a4b With this, his class becomes `class mySubscriber : public subscribable<bool(int), bool(std::string), bool(int, std::string)> {};`

Comment: @Mooning Duck, yes you're right, clarified this with Pasha in chat.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, yeah I find your solution quite fitting here since the signature registration looks quite minimal (would be a nice feature to leave that as a requirement totally). Only this raw pointer usage looks a bit outdated and might be reconsidered as some kind of uniquePtr-scheme I think since the according struct has some interface character.

Comment: Which pointers? `subscribable* subscribed_` is non owning, so definitely _cannot_ be an owning smart pointer, and... that appears to be the only pointer? And it's only used by the return value of `ss.getSubscribe(...)`

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes you're right, sorry. But as far as I can see: you're still using n internal maps still. I think there might be a solution to avoid that, maybe via a hybrid of your and my variant approach. See, your mySubscriber will grow in size already only with focus on compile. A variant scheme - despite some extra required padding issues - wouldn't.

Comment: It does still use N internal maps yes, but the difference in memory between one map and N maps is virtually nothing, and N internal  maps means they're smaller->faster, and doesn't require the `isWanted` quasi-reflection.

Comment: Hm, depends on the actual usage case I think but yes, commonly, such registry classes are quite central without that many instances at runtime. But your really nice approach has another drawback: overload ambiguity. You cannot add bool(int) and int(int) to the subscriber as soon as someone tries getSubscribe("callback", 1). Is only an issue if a flexible return type is really desired, I know and might be solved with an optional explicit return type template parameter maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow turn the memberfunction pointers to regular old function pointers, in order to store them in the same container. You have three options that I can come up with:

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
  void foo(int x, int y, int z) {}

  /*
          Putting the instance as the first parameter is crucial, because the
     first argument to a member function call is an implicit this. If instance
     is not the first parameter the compiler has to shift around the argument
     list, otherwise it's a direct forwarding call.
  */
  static void callback(void* instance, int x, int y, int z) {
    return static_cast<Foo*>(instance)->foo(x, y, z);
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  void (*f0)(void*, int, int, int){&Foo::callback};
  /*
          Capturing lambda cannot decay to function pointer, have to use
     std::function or smth. similar
  */
  std::function<void(int, int, int)> f1{
      [&](int x, int y, int z) { return foo.foo(x, y, z); }};
  auto f2 = std::mem_fn(&Foo::foo);

  f0(&foo, 1, 2, 3);
  f1(1, 2, 3);
  f2(&foo, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

Here's a godbolt with the generated assembly https://godbolt.org/z/K9eM4E

Comment: I need different function signatures

Comment: arbitrary signatures or predefined ones, you can use multiple containers or type erasure if you know the types beforehand